# problem in bootstrap modal showing and hiding

Tags: jquery

[image]

friends when clicking on this button for showing modal the screen become blur and model does not show.

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-info btn-lg pull-right"[1] @click="showAddModel()">Add Course</button>
```

jquery Code:

```
showAddModel(){
    $('#addModel').modal('show');
}
```

Comment: Can you add the HTML for your modal please? That may be helpful in solving your problem.

Comment: That HTML is not valid; I don't know what's going on there.

Comment: ok i am updating the problem.